# How to hide the image tag src attribute?

Tags: image, hide, src

I have a question about the `<img>` tag src attribute.

Is it possible to hide the `<img>` tag src attribute when viewing the source in a browser?
If it is possible, how? Please tel me if you have any reliable sources.

Answer (score 2):

**No, it's not possible.**

You can set them dynamically with JS, but you can't hide them. You can store them as base64 encoded strings, and then decode them on the fly which will "hide" them from your page's source.

*However, this is still utterly pointless as in the end, the browser still makes an HTTP request to fetch the image.*

Comment: are you sure? there is no way.

Comment: Yes, I am sure. **There is no way.**

Comment: @user997719 The only way would be to not use images.

Comment: Also, the only winning move is not to play.

Comment: excuse me vzwick, what is obfuscate?

Answer (score 1):

Simply spoken: This is impossible.

You might try to *obfuscate* your image src attributes (JS, Base64, etc), but for the browser to be able to show an image, you'll always end up exposing the image URI.

Which, in turn, means that everyone who knows their firebug will be able to see where your cute kitteh image comes from.

Alternative:
Generate One-Time URIs for your images (quite expensive).

Comment: vzwick, i have question about your alternative. do you mean for every run off our web application we should use another url for its images?

Comment: I don't do it but I want know if there is such alternative or not?

Comment: Yes there is. If there weren't, I wouldn't have mentioned it as (a theoretical) one.

Answer (score 0):

Another good feature is to hide the location paths of your important scripts. I found a great npm plugin for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/location-hide

This works also for php href, src, content it will use everything inside src=""

You need only node.js for creating the exported files. It´s easy to use even if you don´t know node.js

It turns

```
<script src="test/folder/sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

into

```
<script src="TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<link href="gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq" rel="stylesheet">
```

And it generate new jquery include codes like this to include your scripts with javascript in a external file

```
$('[src=\'TNANIuTOLZfmLYwaPDIYhcZDVOWKodqYhysaTeQHFPDhYlDLCOtxZqYmkKAhaSwSgbsYOWlpBzVSBtMZKSfwRqvPSqWVlBBuzHR\']').attr("src", "test/folder/sample.js")  
$('[href=\'gyXeFnOEvZbgTjLvdZRnsyrfhaXqffkDjcdATTouqpIenCalLRXKamuXEtiKbPGCsNrdQIaqTMTNWsLyLFuxygKytaruWzSjKYMq\']').attr("src", "test/stylesheet/perfect-scrollbar.css")
```

Also I would suggest you that you include all of your external javascript codes in 1 single js file. This file you place in the root of your index file that you can make this

```
<script src="./allinone_external_file.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then make right htaccess that nobody can acces this file. You can also make a fake import script for the source code that every body can see. But this file is only a redirect for the real external js file. you make this multiple times as example + use other obfuscation tools. This will protect you from people searching exploits with your javascript codes. I know its no big deal and maybe you can see the jquery include codes if you know how. But anyway its a great protection.